# Dynamically call and print a function's return-value within a loop, overwrite previous outputs

Tags: python, overwrite

I'm looking for the cleanest way to print a variable dynamically in python 3.

I want to repeatedly call `psutil.virtual_memory()` and print its return-value in place.

Something like this:

```
import psutil
import time

memory = psutil.virtual_memory()

while True:
    print(f"Memory: {memory}")
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Ofcourse that wouldn't be dynamic. I want "memory" to update every 0.5 seconds on the same line.

I couldn't seem to find a clean example of how to do this in this manner.

UPDATE: I'm also wanting to learn how I can do this with multi-line print statements.

Like this

```
Memory:    500MB
CPU Usage: 25%
```

Comment: f-strings allow you to directly print a function call or expression in the first place, so do that directly already: `print(f"Memory: {psutil.virtual_memory()}")`. There was never any need to store the stale return value. Also, *"Dynamically print a variable"* is kind of tortured language, you don't create an ongoing association between a function and its (possibly volatile) return value just by assigning its output once.

Comment: Also when you say *"print the value in-place"*, you actually mean ***"overwrite the output from previous print"***

Comment: ...whereas  "in-place" usually refers to variable assignment without allocating new memory. Not to "overwrite on the console"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `print(..., end='\r')` to the end of your printing statement.

This brings the cursor to the beginning of the line, so subsequent prints will overwrite it.

Comment: That's not strictly an answer to the question asked, also it depends if the particular console supports it. And it would break if there were multiple threads or other print statements.

Comment: @smci I think it actually is. Quote: "I'm trying to have it update in place".

Comment: This works but not for `psutil.virtual_memory`. I guess I'll have to parse the output. Works great for other `psutil` functions however.

Comment: @DarthCadeus: no it's not, it'll break if there are other threads printing. It wasn't clear what *"print the value in-place"* meant, apparently it means ***"overwrite the output from previous print"***.

Comment: @smci: still, I do not believe (short of screen painting with curses) there are any other ways of doing this. (although there probably is)

Comment: @DarthCadeus: but that's answering a question that was never phrased. I just edited *", overwrite previous outputs"* onto the question (yes even though it's been closed already). Many users would not understand *"in place"* as referring to "overwrite (on the console)", "in-place" usually refers to variable assignment without allocating new memory.

Comment: @smci Yeah I inferred from the OP's comment. ("That still prints on a new line every iteration") I forgot to quote this part.

Comment: @DarthCadeus: uhuh. Every time I see a new user ask a misphrased, misstated or unstated question, I help them tweak the title (or else edit it according to what is actually being asked); also retag, and suggest related or duplicate answers. Otherwise this is not a reusable resource for all other users, current and future; and it can't be found by them under keywords or terms.

Answer (score 2):

f-strings allow you to directly print a function call or expression in the first place, so do that. (No need to store the stale return value to a variable, in the first place)

```
while True:
    print(f"Memory: {psutil.virtual_memory()}")
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

UPDATE: after you accepted an answer, we infer that when you say *"print the value in-place"*, you actually mean ***"overwrite the output (on console) from previous print"***

*"in-place"* is actually a different term that usually refers to *"variable assignment without allocating new memory"*. Better to say *"overwrite on the console"*.

Answer (score 0):

Add carriage return with flush for print.

```
import psutil
import time

def memory():
    return psutil.virtual_memory()

while True:
    print(f"Memory: {memory()}", end="\r", flush=True)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```